# python colab issue with wand library

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, issue-tracking, wand

**greetings  ---**

hey gues , I have an a problem with google.colab when I want to run this code :

```
     # Import Image from wand.image module
from wand.image import Image

# Read image using Image() function
with Image(filename ="/content/Hand.jpeg") as img:

    # Generate noise image using spread() function
    img.noise("poisson", attenuate = 0.9)
    img.save(filename ="noise_hand.jpeg")
```

the issue is with this command :

```
from wand.image import Image
```

it keep saying :

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-c8294d82387e> in <module>()
      1 # Import Image from wand.image module
----> 2 from wand.image import Image
```

this issue only appears in colab, I mean, for example, it works fine with Microsoft visual studio.

***pls guess someone help me to fix this problem, and thanks in advance***

note: I already installed and imported the wand library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try installing ImageMagick by running these in a cell before your code.

```
!sudo apt install imagemagick
!pip install wand
```